# How can I load assets dynamically on user's input in LibGDX HTML?

Tags: libgdx, input, html5, assets, preload

I am working with LibGDX and GWT and I am trying to publish my app as a HTML webapp, it has many assets with around hundred of folders, now I want to load them dynamically (user input is sent to JSNI, and security issues set aside), I want to be able to add more assets later without having to recompile the entire thing or creating new assets.txt file.

Here is how the app works. A user select a `foldername` from an HTML dropdown, this will trigger an javascript function created by JSNI: `load(foldername)`. The app then load the files inside `foldername` and use it by accessing `FileHandle file` provided by `Gdx.files.internal(file)`

My goal is to be able to add more assets later on without recompiling/touching the java source code, and to eliminate load time so as not to preload hundreds of assets

I was unable to find similar problem anywhere on the Internet and I am fairly new to this field.

Workaround can be accepted too. I am using LibGDX 1.9.12 and GWT 2.8.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I settled with [this solution](http://nexsoftware.net/wp/2013/07/07/libgdx-deferred-asset-loading-with-gwt/). Be sure to checkout the example project at the bottom of the article to have things work properly